capawesome-team/capacitor-nfc compile error
I am using the capawesome-team/capacitor-nfc plugin and when I try to compile the application for android I am having this problem
enter image description here
I have installed and configured the plugin according to the documentation https://capawesome.io/plugins/nfc/
error import android.nfc.AvailableNfcAntenna;
^
symbol:   class AvailableNfcAntenna
location: package android.nfc

Hi, I'm the maintainer of this plugin. Please create a bug report on GitHub and provide a minimal, reproducible example. I'll then immediately take a look at it.

Hello, I think it was a compatibility problem with the version of @capacitor/core I had the 5.5.0 and I had to upgrade to version 6.2.0, I also had to update the other dependencies.

Please don't add images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].
